# Using 2d array as datasource of word mailmarge datasource in vb6

Tags: vb6, datasource, multidimensional-array, mailmerge, word-automation

I'm creating a word automation in vb6 to create mail marge for mailing labels.[**Here**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258512) is a help link to do it using a text file as data source. Now I want to do it using a 2d array as data source. I don't know how to use the 2d array instead the text file as data source. Please help.

Comment: Word can't use in-memory objects or structures directly as the data source for a standard (out-of-the-box) MailMerge. You either need to save your array in a format that Word can use, or "roll your own merge". The only exception I know of would be if you had an ODBC driver or OLE DB provider that could get data from your array: unlikely, and even then, Word always needs to reference some kind of external file or object (such as a DSN) when connecting via OpenDataSource.

Comment: @bibadiak :: Is there any other ways to connect instead OpenDataSource?

Comment: I would follow bibadiaks advice and save your 2D array data to a COMMA delimited TEXT file and simply use that as the datasource.

Comment: Yes. I also did so to get my work done.